# error install phpunit-skeleton generator

Tags: installation, pear

I have been trying to install phpunit skeleton generator. I started with

```
ear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de                 
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is already initialised
```

phpunit is working and upon trying to install the skeleton generator I get the following message which I dont understand how to resolve it. I dont know where to start looking to resolve this so some pointer would be gratefully received

```
pear remote-list

Warning: lstat(): Lstat failed for /var/folders/jb/60nkj_096yq3kkpg_p4czs4c5cr2p_/T//pear/cache/e9b88593398eb69a9ff91042351d646arest.cacheid in PEAR/REST.php on line 276
PHP Warning:  lstat(): Lstat failed for /var/folders/jb/60nkj_096yq3kkpg_p4czs4c5cr2p_/T//pear/cache/e9b88593398eb69a9ff91042351d646arest.cacheid in /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.23/lib/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 276

Warning: lstat(): Lstat failed for /var/folders/jb/60nkj_096yq3kkpg_p4czs4c5cr2p_/T//pear/cache/e9b88593398eb69a9ff91042351d646arest.cacheid in /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.23/lib/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 276
Could not open /var/folders/jb/60nkj_096yq3kkpg_p4czs4c5cr2p_/T//pear/cache/e9b88593398eb69a9ff91042351d646arest.cacheid for writing.


myname@mycomp:~ » pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator                                                         1 ↵

Warning: lstat(): Lstat failed for /var/folders/jb/60nkj_096yq3kkpg_p4czs4c5cr2p_/T//pear/cache/b116edc6554e2f3e3c908e2a309732a8rest.cacheid in PEAR/REST.php on line 276
PHP Warning:  lstat(): Lstat failed for /var/folders/jb/60nkj_096yq3kkpg_p4czs4c5cr2p_/T//pear/cache/b116edc6554e2f3e3c908e2a309732a8rest.cacheid in /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.23/lib/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 276

Warning: lstat(): Lstat failed for /var/folders/jb/60nkj_096yq3kkpg_p4czs4c5cr2p_/T//pear/cache/b116edc6554e2f3e3c908e2a309732a8rest.cacheid in /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.23/lib/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 276
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator"

install failed
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you need to prefix your pear remote-list command with sudo, and execute it as root.

```
$ sudo pear remote-list
```

You would need to do this for installing packages too. This is perfectly normal (for installing packages).